# List values and values from dictionary not working together. Simple Python test-project

Tags: python, tkinter, colors, euclidean-distance

I'm trying to create something that would let the user to pick a color and it would return the closest match from the hardcoded list of colors.

I'm completely new to python and I definitely have many more problems with my code but the one thing that I'm not able to work out currently is that my `selected_color` is probably returning a different type than needed in my distance calculation, so it's always returning the same, wrong value.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import colorchooser
import math

root = Tk()
root.title("ColorChooser")
root.geometry("400x400")

def get_color():
    c_1 = (254, 252, 245)
    c_2 = (8, 20, 60)
    c_3 = (150, 105, 100)
    c_4 = (146, 19, 13)
    c_5 = (103, 80, 54)
    c_6 = (237, 90, 2)
    c_7 = (220, 136, 9)
    c_8 = (250, 240, 0)

    hardcoded_color = [c_1, c_2, c_3, c_4, c_5, c_6, c_7, c_8]
    color_list = []

    selected_color = colorchooser.askcolor()[0]
    print(selected_color)
    label_color = colorchooser.askcolor()[1]
    my_label = Label(root, text=label_color).pack(pady=10)
    my_label2 = Label(root, text="Your color", font=("Helvetica", 32), bg=label_color).pack()
   

    for i in range (len(hardcoded_color)):
        use_color = hardcoded_color[i] 
        distance = math.sqrt(sum([(a - b) ** 2 for a, b in zip(use_color, selected_color)]))
        color_list.append(distance)

    print("Euclidean distance from x to y: ", color_list)
    closest_color = min(color_list)
    index = color_list.index(closest_color)
    print(hardcoded_color[index])

my_button = Button(root, text="Pick A Color", command=get_color).pack()



root.mainloop()
```

*bonus question: To display the closest matching color to the user, I'm going to have to somehow hardcode or calculate the hex code, yes?

Comment: It seems, there are two places where something could go wrong: **1.** in the distance calculation, and **2.** when interpreting the input from the user. Try simplifying your code by figuring out which of the two is responsible for the problem.

Comment: I've run your code. And only issue I see is that it asks twice to get color. Otherwise, it calculates distance fine and depending on what you choose, you get a different answer

Comment: @AleksandarVaricak Ok, I think I just have too little colors to for comparing. It kept returning the same color for me and I really thought there was something wrong.

Comment: This makes no sense: `label_color = colorchooser.askcolor()[1]`. You are asking the user for another color and then use that for the label, but that's not what you use in the calculation?

Comment: @asynts I've tested it more and I think I need more colors for comparisons, because it kept returning the same result for me over and over. I automatically thought there was something wrong with my code.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference (you probably shouldn't use Euclidean distance or make your colors more uniformly-distributed)

Comment: Every time you call `colorchooser.askcolor()` it will prompt you for another color! If you want to refer to the same value again you need to save it in a variable.

Comment: @asynts that's where I get the hex code, to display to the user. For the calculation I only need the RGB.

Comment: But you are asking the user twice? You can get the hex value for the value they picked with `response = colorchooser.askcolor()` and then `response[1]` or `response[0]`.

Comment: You can get the RGB and hex code together from the result of `askcolor()`, so you don't need to call it twice.

Comment: @asynts I didn't even notice that. Thank you. Will make repairs.

Comment: @acw1668 I didn't even realize, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, Label
from tkinter.colorchooser import askcolor
import math

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Tkinter Color Chooser')
root.geometry('300x150')


def change_color():
    colors = askcolor(title="Tkinter Color Chooser")
    my_label = Label(root, text=colors[1]).pack(pady=10)
    my_label2 = Label(root, text="Your color", font=("Helvetica", 32), bg=colors[1]).pack()
    root.configure(bg=colors[1])
    
    c_1 = (254, 252, 245)
    c_2 = (8, 20, 60)
    c_3 = (150, 105, 100)
    c_4 = (146, 19, 13)
    c_5 = (103, 80, 54)
    c_6 = (237, 90, 2)
    c_7 = (220, 136, 9)
    c_8 = (250, 240, 0)

    hardcoded_color = [c_1, c_2, c_3, c_4, c_5, c_6, c_7, c_8]
    color_list = []

    selected_color = colors[0]
    print(selected_color)
     
   

    for i in range (len(hardcoded_color)):
        use_color = hardcoded_color[i] 
        distance = math.sqrt(sum([(a - b) ** 2 for a, b in zip(use_color, selected_color)]))
        color_list.append(distance)

    print("Euclidean distance from x to y: ", color_list)
    closest_color = min(color_list)
    index = color_list.index(closest_color)
    print(hardcoded_color[index])


ttk.Button(
    root,
    text='Select a Color',
    command=change_color).pack(expand=True)


root.mainloop()
```

Output:

[image]